# PHP pages restricted access by access level

Tags: php, mysql

In MySQL table I have:

1. ID
2. username
3. password
4. level

level "admin" = access to all pages
level "user" = access only to certain pages

---

In auth.php page (which is included in every page).

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit(); 
}
```

In login page I have:

```
session_start();

// If form submitted, insert values into the database. 
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {

    $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']); // removes backslashes
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username); //escapes special characters in a string
    $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $password);

    //Checking is user existing in the database or not
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='" . md5($password) . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($rows == 1) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("Location: index.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
    } else {
        header("Location: login.php"); // Redirect user to index.php;
    }
};
```

How should I make two sessions, session for "admin" and session for "user", so every page would have different access level?

Comment: its not 2 sessions, it just `$_SESSION['level'] = $level;` $level being querried from the db

Comment: What is the point of doing `stripslashes()`? Don't tell me you're using PHP 5.3 with [magic_quotes_gpc enabled](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc)... Also, `md5` is not appropriate for hashing passwords. Instead use [password_hash()](http://php.net/password_hash).

Comment: Yes, when I place that inside login.php, how to restrict it on, let's say, index.php where is only session_start(); and body text?

Comment: not entirely sure of the question but .. `if($_SESSION['level'] !='admin'){//whatever you want here}`

Comment: @smith, that goes on which page , auth.php or index.php?

Comment: on the page you want to validate user level

Comment: It goes where you check the credentials

Comment: I see what wrong your not actually pulling Data from database and are using the $username posted. I would pull it from the Database. $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); Your just cheking if you have a row but you want to fetch the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($con,$query)) {


        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $_SESSION['username'] = $row["username"];
         $_SESSION['level'] = $row["level"]);
        }

        $result->free();
    }
```

Aftert that when a page requires a certain level just verify if the level is right.